# scala - remained time in a textField

Tags: scala, timer

I have a text field which is supposed to hold some manualy given minutes, then I need this given number (these minutes) to be decreased by a timer (I already have configured a timer to give me ticks every 1 second), but I am struggling to find how I can do it simply; can it help if I try to use

```
scala.concurrent.duration._
```

frankly, I haven't take a look on it before. Or any other suggestion is welcomed.

---

My current solution, for somebody that may need it:

```
class ScalaTimer(val delay: Int) {
  val tmr: javax.swing.Timer = new javax.swing.Timer(delay, null)
  def start() = tmr.start()
  def stop() = tmr.stop()
 }

object Test33 { //extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  val timer = new ScalaTimer(1000)
  timer.start
  var remainedtime: Int = 10
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    timer.tmr.addActionListener(Swing.ActionListener(e => {  
      val tm = remainedtime - 1
      remainedtime = tm
      println(tm)
  }))

  Thread.sleep(10000);
 }
```

Lets hope that I may use it now, as I want :)

Comment: oh; I am obliged to do it pure in Scala. It's 1/10000 part of my App and I wouldn't like to spent so much time on it :( that's why I am searching for a suggestion in which direction I should go without losing much time.

Comment: That seems simple enough already. The only doubt I have is that you said that the textbox contains minutes, but in your test you are decreasing the value every second instead than every minute. I hope it's just for testing and you are aware of this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this one was just to test it, currently I have changed it alot :D